# Need help in understanding how to 3d surface plot using plotly

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, surface

I am trying to plot a function z= sinx cosy over -pi to pi

[This is what I'm hoping to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OTsx.jpg)

[Also shown like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJBVQ.png)

This is the code I have written in an attempt to do the same:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz

x=np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,30)
z = [(np.sin(i)*np.cos(i)) for i in x]

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(x=x, y=x, z=toeplitz(z))])
fig.show()
```

[plotly output that I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjovv.png)

I have not been able to understand what 'grid' or '2d array' format I have to convert my z co-ordinate column data into for getting the right graph. Toeplitz was an attempt to do the same, but it seems symmetric unlike the required graph. Please help

Answer (score 2):

I think I've got it, if you're facing similar issue you can refer/use the code below

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
f = lambda x,y: np.sin(x) * np.cos(y)
x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 30)
y = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 30)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
F = f(X,Y)

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(x=X, y=Y, z=F)])
fig.show()
```